# fineuploader with overall progressbar

Tags: jquery, upload, fine-uploader

I'm using fineuploader to upload photos to my website.
I can get and update progress for each file with,

```
.on('progress', function (event, id, filename, uploadedBytes, totalBytes)
```

but how can I get the overall progress?

Comment: `uploadedBytes / totalBytes`?

Comment: uploadedBytes / totalBytes will return the progress for each file not overall progress (i'm uploading several files simultaneously

Comment: What plugin is this? Where's the documentation?

Comment: http://fineuploader.com/

Comment: After looking at the docs (very briefly) it doesn't look like there's a surefire way of doing that. My suggestion would be to count the total amount of selected files and after each file successfully uploads, move a progress bar X% (100%/QTY=X). You can count the files by doing `.on('submitted', function(event, id, filename) {
filesToUpload++; }`

Comment: Have a look at my answer, which shows how to do this properly using the `progress` event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the docs (very briefly) it doesn't look like there's a surefire way of doing that. My suggestion would be to count the total amount of selected files and after each file successfully uploads, move a progress bar X%.

```
<div class="tot_progress" style="width:500px;">
    <div class="bar" style="width:0; color:green;"></div>
</div>

.on('submitted', function(event, id, filename) {
    filesToUpload++;
})
.on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {                            
    uploadedFiles++;
    prog_width = Math.floor(100/filesToUpload)*uploadedFiles;
    $('.bar').css('width',prog_width+'%');
})
```

For example, let's say we had 4 files to upload. After the first file completes the progress bar would show 25%, when the second file completes the bar would show 50%... You could animate the width which would make it look prettier.

Comment: I would not recommend doing it this way, unless you are uploading very small files that are all about the same size.  A true progress bar should be much more responsive than this, as it should update as actual bytes are sent to the server.  My answer shows how to do this.

Comment: @RayNicholus I can understand there is a more advanced/precise method for real-time progress, but there is nothing wrong with the method I've suggested. I'm only getting defensive because you used the words "I would not recommend doing it this way" as if there was something wrong with it. It would have been a bit better if you'd wrote "There's a better way to achieve this". I happen to like my method of showing a percentage of completion only when a file actually completes.

Comment: Fair enough.  I just assumed that the OP wanted to mirror the behavior of the built-in per-file progress bar that Fine Uploader provides.

Answer (score 3):

As an update to this question, there is a remarkably simple and effective way to do this now.  Documentation at [docs.fineuploader.com](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#totalProgress), and it is also possible to get updates [as a progress bar](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/progress-bars.html).  I also find this text is nice to combine with [Bootstrap's Progress Bar / Label functionality](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress).

```
$(element).fineUploader({
...
})
.on("totalProgress", function(event, totalUploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
  var progressPercent = (totalUploadedBytes / totalBytes).toFixed(2);
  if(isNaN(progressPercent)) {
    $('#progress-text').text('');
  } else {
    var progress = (progressPercent * 100).toFixed() + '%';

    $('#progress-text').text(progress);
  }
});
```

And here is the related code for the front-end tying to bootstrap:

```
<div id="progress-bar-container" class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector progress">
  <div id="progress-bar" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar">
    <span id="progress-text"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to preserve the Bootstrap ARIA/screen reader integration, you can add hooks for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very difficult to do this, and it's much better than simply incrementing the progress bar after each file completes.  You need to make use of the [`progress` event](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#progress), for the most part.  In fact, I even detailed [how you can create your own aggregate progress bar in a blog post I wrote](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/11/01/full-stack-javascript-image-uploader-using-angularjs-node-js/#angular-progress).

For example (from the blog post):

```
var perFileProgress = {};

$(element).fineUploader({
    ...
    callbacks: {
        onProgress: function(id, name, sent, total) {
            perFileProgress[id] = [sent, total];
            updateTotalProgress();
        },

        onCancel: function(id) {
            if (qq.supportedFeatures.progressBar) {
                delete perFileProgress[id];
                updateTotalProgress();
            }
        },

        onComplete: function(id, name, response) {
            if (!response.success) {
                delete perFileProgress[id];
                updateTotalProgress();
            }
        }
        ...
    }
});

function updateTotalProgress() {
    var $container = $("#totalProgress"),
        $bar = $container.find(".progress-bar"),
        totalSent = 0,
        totalSize = 0,
        percentComplete = 0;

    $.each(perFileProgress, function(fileId, progressData) {
        totalSent += progressData[0];
        totalSize += progressData[1];
    });
    percentComplete = Math.round((totalSent/totalSize) * 100);

    if (totalSent !== totalSize) {
        $bar.css({
            width: percentComplete + "%"
        });

        $container.removeClass("hide");
    }
    else {
        $container.addClass("hide");
    }
}
```

Note: My code above assumes you are using bootstrap, but this is certainly not required, and you can remove the dependency on bootstrap pretty easily if desired.